# Custom PHP error handling without showing PHP errors as well

Tags: php, error-handling

I have code that handles errors while running multiple functions. One of them is `simplexml_load_file()`. I'm doing something like this:

```
$input_xml = simplexml_load_file($input_file);
if(!$input_xml)
{
    fwrite($STDERR, $errors["XML_ERR"]);
    exit(1);
}
```

But my terminal shows multiple warnings when the variable `$input_file` is empty, and at the end, it shows my custom error message. Is there any other (better) way to handle these types of errors so I get only one message (my custom one)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [turn off the warnings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), but they're there for a reason. Make sure your variable is initialized, [because uninitialized variables tend to make a program non-deterministic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/223916).

In your case, something like

```
if (isset($input_file) && $input_file != "") {
   // put your simplexml_load_file here...
}
```

...or something even better like checking if `$input_file` is really a file which can be accessed should do the job.

Comment: Great, totally forgot about encapsulating it into a positive condition rather than a negative one. This solves it gracefully, thanks!